# How to import VMs from files on NFS server local to XenServer

Tags: xen, xenserver, xencenter

I have a XenServer running in my co-location rack and my XenCenter is running at home and connected to it.

What I am trying to do is create some VMs by importing XVA files, but those XVA files are on an NFS server local to the XenServer.  The XenServer does have a Storage Resource (SR) on that same XenServer but at a different share point.

If I try to create another SR at the NFS share point where the XVA files are it does not recognize the XVA files as anything I can import. They are not visible at all.

What I don't want to do is copy those XVA files to the system where I am running XenCenter so I can do an import (menu File -> Import) from there.  That would take too much time given that would be two transfers (one down, then back up) of 500GB files via a cable modem.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the nfs server is local to the XenServer then you should be able to simply use scp to copy the files from one to the other without involving the cable modem connection (other then to issue the commands).

```
nfs_server$ scp a.xva myuser@xenserver.example.com:~
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the XenServer hypervisor environment includes NFS client tools, so it is fairly easy to mount a volume where the source XVA files are and import them using a **xe** command.  So:

```
$ xe sr-list
```

Will get you a list of available Storage Repositories where you want the VM to reside.  Copy the UUID for that repository.   Then you can use that UUID to construct the command below:

```
$ mount someserver.com:/some/path /mnt
$ xe vm-import filename=/mnt/MyPreciousVM.xva sr-uuid=40c123a7-7842-dead-beef-fc67ff272291
```

Once done you you can then go to XenCenter to work with the object.